# Angular: How to check change in queryParams before ngOnDestroy is called

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I would like to conditionally execute some code in `ngOnDestroy` based on changes in current route.

Route is changed from `/foo` to `/login?logout=true`, and this change is triggered outside of Foo component.

In `ngOnInit` I am subscribing to queryParam changes, to update correctly `loggingOut` flag.

My problem is, that `ngOnDestroy` is called before next handler of queryParam, so the `loggingOut` has incorrect value.

```
export class FooComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    
    loggingOut = false;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(queryParams => {
            this.loggingOut = queryParams.get('logout') === 'true';
        });

    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        if (this.loggingOut) {
            // do this
        } else {
            // do that
        }
    }
}
```

Seems this is intended behavior from lifecycle POV, so have following question:

- Is there a way to check route changes before `ngOnDestory` is called?

If possible, please add link to documentation describing, how are lifecycle hooks (especially `ngOnDestory`) called with respect to navigation changes?

Thanks.

Comment: Angular routing is not working that way. You have to "do this" on Logout page, and "do that" on the alternative route.

Comment: could you please add a link to some resource, that would explain it a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

**My problem is, that ngOnDestroy is called before next handler of queryParam**

```
componentDestroyed = false;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(queryParams => {
        if (!this.componentDestroyed)
            this.loggingOut = queryParams.get('logout') === 'true';
        else {
           // Do here what you wanted to do in ngOnDestroy
        }
    });

}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.componentDestroyed = true;
}
```

Would this fix your problem?

Comment: unfortunately not, because on "that" branch I am saving component state to store and dont want to do it every time route params change, anyway thanks